# In App Purchases not working in iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, prime31

I am developing an iOS game in Unity3d using the prime31's plugin for In App Purchases, but it doesn't work on iOS 7.0.3. The app just crashes as soon as I initialize the In App module. The important thing to note is that this code and plugin is working perfectly in iOS 7.0.2 and below.

To debug the problem I created a native sample app and in it the following callback function is never called in iOS 7.0.3

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

and purchasing any product also produces a crash.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please, show symbolicated crash report.

Comment: Whenever I run into any issues with prime31 I always click the update plugins to make sure I have the latest.  If that doesn't solve the problem, you might want to check their own support [forum](http://prime31.com/support/)